# find_first of a vector in parallel in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, parallel-processing, openmp

I have a quite big vector. Some of the vector members are matching a certain condition in parallel. I would like to find the first element matching to the condition.

My problem is very similar to this question ([tbb: parallel find first element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726864/tbb-parallel-find-first-element)) , but I do not have tbb. Checking condition is very tedious (so I cannot do it for all of them sequentially). That's why I would like to run it in parallel. I have to mention that I would like to find the first element (so the index position of the element is important for me).

For exmple if I have 4 threads.

```
ThreadNr   Index      condition
1            0         Not Meet
2            1         Not Meet
3            2         Not Meet
4            3         Not Meet

ThreadNr   Index      condition
1            4         Not Meet
2            5          Meet
3            6         Not Meet
4            7          Meet
```

The function has to retun index number of 5.
Threads have to be distributed and work on sequential iteration block (block size can be more that 1. For instance thread 1 works on the first 4 elements, thread 2 on the second 4 elements and so on).

For above example if thread number 4 (in index 7) found member before thread number 2 (in index 5), it must wait all thread finish the job. As I said before the lowest index number is the target.

Please correct me if you have a better algorithm in mind.

NOTE: I can use external libraries such as boost 1.62, OpenMP 2.0

Comment: Note that best-case complexity increases from 0 to N/K, where N is the total number of elements and K is the number of threads.

Comment: It depends a lot on the size of the elements and how long the checking condition takes. If you are doing something simple like `==` against a `std::vector<int>` you wouldn't want to interleave like that because it'd cause havoc on the cache. In that case you might want threads checking blocks of integers at a time. If your vector objects are 1mb a piece and it takes 1-2 seconds to perform a check, that interleaving might make more sense.

Comment: If tbb appeals  to  you use  it.  In  Openmp if I understand  the question you  would partition  data   as you appear to have done with inner search loop,  combining   inner  results  in outer  omp  reduction  firstprivate  lastprivate  or critical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since OpenMP 2.0 does not have cancellation constructs, you have to implement one on your own, e.g., by using a shared variable. It also means that you cannot use the `for` worksharing construct as breaking out of parallel loops is not permitted (that's why OpenMP 4.0 introduced cancellation constructs). If you implement cancellation checks between the evaluation of each element, it might happen that two or more threads find elements matching the criterion. Thus, you should perform a min reduction on the index:

```
int found = 0;
int first_index = INVALID_VALUE;
int iteration = 0;

#pragma omp parallel
{
   int my_index = INVALID_VALUE;
   int i;

   do
   {
      // Later versions of OpenMP allow for "atomic capture"
      // but OpenMP 2.0 requires a critical directive instead
      #pragma omp critical(iteration)
      {
         i = iteration++;
      }

      if (i < N && check(i))
      {
         found = 1;
         my_index = i;
      }
   } while (!found && i < N);

   #pragma omp critical(reduction)
   if (my_index != INVALID_VALUE)
   {
      if (first_index == INVALID_VALUE || my_index < first_index)
         first_index = my_index;
   }

   // Only needed if more code follows before the end of the region
   #pragma omp barrier

   ...
}
```

This code assumes that checking the condition for the i-th element (`check(i)`) does not alter the state of the element, and therefore, the worst that could happen is that the thread that has found a matching element might have to wait for all other threads to finish checking the element they currently work on and that waiting time will be the maximum of all processing times.

The `critical` construct used in the do-loop is expensive. If `check()` doesn't take that much time, then you might consider working with chunks instead of iterations:

```
do
{
   #pragma omp critical(chunk)
   {
       my_chunk = chunk++;
   }

   if (my_chunk >= N_chunks)
      break;

   for (i = my_chunk * chunk_size; !found && i < (my_chunk+1)*chunk_size; i++)
   {
      if (check(i))
      {
         found = 1;
         my_index = i;
         break;
      }
   }
} while (!found && my_chunk < N_chunks);
```

---

Another solution that works reasonably well when the number of elements is not that big and checking each one is expensive:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
   #pragma omp for schedule(dynamic,x)
   for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
   {
      if (!found && check(i))
      {
         my_index = i;
         found = 1;
      }
   }

   // Min reduction from the solution above
   ...
}
```

Once `found` becomes true, the rest of the loop iterations will run "empty" bodies because the shortcutting properties of `&&`.

Comment: just a question: for the last solution, don't you need to flush `found` somewhere?

Comment: In addition to my previous comment, the two first solutions do not need a `flush` since some are implied by the `critical` sections within the loops. But for the last solution, there is no implicit or explicit flush of `found` which could therefore be kept untouched in cache by the threads not having found the solution. At least, this is how I see it. Am I wrong?

Comment: `found` was `volatile` initially, then I removed it. Indeed, the relaxed memory model allows for shared variables to have temporarily divergent values in different threads, but proper use of `flush` is tricky and I'd rather not introduce the construct here. Besides, most OpenMP compilers on x86 tend to implement a stricter memory model (not keeping after assignment shared variables in registers only) and `flush` is compiled to a memory fence. Without flush it could lead to an additional iteration, so no big deal. But for the sake of correctness, yes, there should be one.

Answer (score 0):

With OpenMP you can try to build a for loop with `#pragma omp for schedule(dynamic)`. Each thread will execute one iteration in same order as your vector.
If you want to check 4 elements by thread, try `#pragma omp for schedule(dynamic, 4)`

Comment: Thanks but it does not respect the indexation. For example if thread number 4 found the element before thread number 2. I may get the wring index

Comment: I think that if the condition is ok, you can add `#pragma omp ordered` before writing the value of the index and exiting the loop.